# Create RSA signature from third party supplied key within a certificate

Tags: key, rsa, signature

REQUIREMENT
Our website will be sending our customers to a third party website and the third party requires that we: 
•   Create a RSA signature generated us the value of a token we will create which consists of(    Timestamp + “|” + Policy Number ) and pass this in query string url during the redirect.  When creating the signature, we will use a unique certificate that the third party will supply containing the proper key to use when signing. 
•   Then the third party will validate the signature and retrieve the data from the token

I have the code working for the token creating the  signature and verifying it, see EX-A code  below with a .NET generate RSA key.

We do not have the certificate from the third party yet with the key. Since I am new at this I want to prepare for coding to use the key they provide.  I have some very elementary questions, I need some help and directions please.

QUESTIONS
1.  Is it possible for me to do a one time extract of their key and put it in the C# constant variable compiled dll to use on the website?
           If so how would I change the code below to use that key?
2.  If not possible to do one time extract -  must it be stored on the webserver and my local machine to run my local website please explain the steps and how to extract.  Where should it be stored? What type of file will it be?

EX-A Code
This code  works just fine and it uses a .NET generated RSA key

public class VfbRSASafeliteCryption
    {

```
    public static string SafeliteEncodedSignature(string policyNumber)
    {
        var returnSignature = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var requestedPolicyNumber = policyNumber;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestedPolicyNumber))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            String timeStamp = currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");


            //TOKEN is data to sign.   timestamp+ | + polnum
            String tokenString = timeStamp + "|" + policyNumber;

            // Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
            ASCIIEncoding ByteConverter = new ASCIIEncoding();

            // Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted 
            byte[] originalData = ByteConverter.GetBytes(tokenString);
            byte[] signedData;

            // Create a new instance of the RSACryptoServiceProvider class automatically create a new key-pair.
            RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            // Export the key information to an RSAParameters object.
            // You must pass true to export the private key for signing.
            // However, you do not need to export the private key
            // for verification.
            RSAParameters Key = RSAalg.ExportParameters(true);    //TODO use a key from safelite

            // Hash and sign the data.
            signedData = HashAndSignBytes(originalData, Key);

            // Verify the data 
            if (VerifySignedHash(originalData, signedData, Key))
            {
                //64encode
                returnSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);

            }
            else
            {
                //todo logging
                return string.Empty;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //todo logging
            return string.Empty;

        }

        return returnSignature;
    }

    public static byte[] HashAndSignBytes(byte[] DataToSign, RSAParameters Key)
    {
        // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider using the 
        // key from RSAParameters.
        using (var RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            try
            {

                RSAalg.ImportParameters(Key);

                // Hash and sign the data. Pass a new instance of SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
                // to specify the use of SHA1 for hashing.
               return RSAalg.SignData(DataToSign, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
                // ALT code below
                // return RSAalg.SignData(DataToSign, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"));
            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Set the keycontainer to be cleared when rsa is garbage collected.
                RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static bool VerifySignedHash(byte[] DataToVerify, byte[] SignedData, RSAParameters Key)
    {
        // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider using the 
        // key from RSAParameters.
        using (var RSAalg = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            try
            {

               RSAalg.ImportParameters(Key);

                // Verify the data using the signature.  Pass a new instance of SHA1CryptoServiceProvider
                // to specify the use of SHA1 for hashing.
                return RSAalg.VerifyData(DataToVerify, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), SignedData);
                //ALT CODE 
                // return RSAalg.VerifyData(DataToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"), SignedData);

            }
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Set the keycontainer to be cleared when rsa is garbage collected.
                RSAalg.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *When creating the signature, we will use a unique certificate that the third party will supply containing the proper key to use when signing.*
Sorry, this doesn't make any sense. You generate your own key and keep the private key secure. The third party cannot give it to you.

Comment: The Paperwork from the third party says "a unique certifcate will be given to you containing the proper key to use when signing the token"

Comment: in my code put up here I am generating my own keys.  See questions in my post they are referring to what do i need to do when I do receive the certificate with the key they want me to use.  Thanks in advance for all comments and help.